# How do I use the generic type of this class's generic type (Java)?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism, wildcard

I have an abstract class `A<T>` with generic wildcard T. There are two extensions of A,

```
public class A1 extends A<Integer> {...}
```

and

```
public class A2 extends A<String> {...}
```

Now I have another class, let's call it B, that is basically a collection of either A1 or A2. So I defined it as a class of generic type T extends A:

```
public class B<T extends A> {...}
```

What I would like to be able to do is, within B, create methods that return the type of T's generic. For example,

```
B<A1> foo = new B<A1>;
foo.get(); // returns Integer, corresponding to A1's generic type
```

and

```
B<A2> bar = new B<A2>;
bar.get(); // returns String, corresponding to A2's generic type
```

Is it possible to do this in Java? I'm having trouble figuring out what return type to put when declaring B's methods (if I wanted B to return T, I'd put `public T get() {...}`, but I actually want to return the parametrized type *of* T). Or is there a pattern that solves this problem better than the way I'm approaching it?

Thanks.

Comment: `T` is the generic type of `T`, and `B` (as posted) for both `foo` and `bar` is a [`Raw Type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) (which is another way of saying it isn't generic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a second type parameter for `B` and have that be the parameterization of `A`

```
class B<K, T extends A<K>> {
    public K get() {
        // actual implementation
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then declare your variables

```
B<String, A2> var = new B<>();
String ret = var.get();
```

---

[What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: You might also be able to remove the parameter `T`, if you don't do anything else with it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. @Sotirios, is this a bad design to use? I'm curious about your link to raw types. I guess I meant `B<A1> foo = new B<A1>`, etc (fixed). Does that change your answer at all? @immibis, I would like `B` to be associated with `T` rather than `K` and I thought that the encapsulated information of `K` might somehow be retrieved from `T`...

Comment: @tytk `A` is a generic type. If you don't parameterized it, you're getting its raw version. So in your snippet, `B<T extends A>` was using `A` as a raw type.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you. So is the extra parameter necessary then? Couldn't I just declare `class B<T extends A<K>>`?

Comment: @tytk `K` is used as a type. It must exist, ie. be declared somewhere. If it's a type variable, it needs to be declared as a type variable, in the generic type parameter declaration list.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Makes sense, it just seems a tad verbose to have to include a type that's already part of the definition of A1 or A2. Thank you.

Comment: @tytk If you didn't care about the parameter of `A`, you would use `class B<T extends A<?>>`

Answer (score 1):

I would like to provide an example that may help you better understand why we would need two generic type parameters. First, the sample declarations of the `A` and its direct subclasses .

```
class A<T> {

    private T value;

    public A(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }   
}

class A1 extends A<Integer> {
    A1(Integer i) {
        super(i);
    }
}

class A2 extends A<String> {
    A2(String str) {
        super(str);
    }
}
```

Now, the `B` class declaration. Notice, how it references both the generic types in its definition to provide access to the members of the wrapped `A` subclass.

```
public class B<T, X extends A<T>> {

    private X data;

    public B(X data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public T get() {
        return data.getValue();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        B<Integer, A1> foo = new B<Integer, A1>(new A1(10));
        System.out.println(foo.get()); // returns Integer

        B<String, A2> bar = new B<String, A2>(new A2("Ten"));
        System.out.println(bar.get()); // returns String
    }
}
```

If you switch to just one type parameter, you have two options.

You either keep the type of the `A` subclass like

```
public class B<T extends A<?>> {

    private T data;

    public B(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Object get() {
        return data.getValue();
    }

    ...
}
```

Or, the actual `return` type of the getter.

```
public class B<T> {

    private T value;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public B(A<?> data) {
        this.value = (T) data.getValue();
    }

    public T get() {
        return value;
    }

    ... 
}
```

Notice, how both the solutions are fragile.

One returning an `Object` and requiring the use of `instanceof` to cast it properly and the other even more brittle with an *unchecked* cast. Since, you're not providing both the generic types you need, you've constrained your class design and run the risk of getting a `ClassCastException` now.

Comment: Thank you! This was a very clear example. It still seems a little unnecessarily verbose to me but I guess that's how Java is. Already accepted the other answer but upvoted this one for helpfulness.

Comment: Just updated my answer to explain: why, what seems like verbosity in Java, is actually required to make the class completely type safe.